# Maven not accepting encrypted nexus password

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have created encrypted password and kept in **settings.xml** like below

```
<servers>
    <server>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>{pOcujvGAOjcHToFaXEAxMD6q6gsHJQiGSNBIprB9uC4=}</password>
</server>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>http://10.220.110.10:8081/repository/halosys-group/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

my **settings-security.xml** looks like below

```
<settingsSecurity>
        <master>{mohoTGlm1YkHYpN2mJ4+Ih8wRQOpwOXa13dUruRuSoM=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

If I keep **password as plain text in settings.xml file mvn deploy command working fine**.

But this when i keep **password as encrypted in setting.xml file mvn deploy command giving error as below**

Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: 
Authentication failed for http://10.220.110.10:8081/repository/halosys-group/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom 401 Unauthorized

Please help to fix this issue with encrypted password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store your plain password in Jenkins credentials store. Check [#adding-new-global-credentials-in-jenkins-credentials-store](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#adding-new-global-credentials)
2. In your `settings.xml`, you can keep like below.

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <username>${project.username}</username>
    <password>${project.password}</password>
</server>
```

3. When running maven from Jenkins, you can use the `withCredentials` directive as below.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mvn-credentials', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
  sh "mvn -s settings.xml clean install -Dproject.username=${USERNAME} -Dproject.password=${PASSWORD}"
}
```

This way you won't have mentioned your password explicitly, but it will be used and even masked in the console output. More on how to use [withCredentials plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables).

Comment: Thanks a lot code working perfectly which fulfill my requirement. I have given the full path of mvn command and settings.xml file its working. Once again thank you so much for helping